# How to highlight the 3 highest values and 3 lowest values in on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently, I only know how to create a dataframe that highlights highest values or a dataframe that highlights lowest values. I want one dataframe with highlight lowest and highest.

The code I currently use to do this (for highest values) is:

def highlight_top3(s):

```
# Get 3 largest values of the column

is_large = s.nlargest(3).values



# Highlight 3 largest values in each principal component

return \['background-color: lightgreen' if v in is_large else '' for v in s\]
```

Comment: `is_small = s.nsmallest(3).values` should work.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,5,6,7,0.5,9,4,5.5]})

def highlight_top3(s):
    
    result = []
    is_large = s.nlargest(3).values
    is_small = s.nsmallest(3).values

    for i in s:
        if i in is_large:
            result.append('background-color: lightgreen')
        elif i in is_small:
            result.append('background-color: #FFCCCB') 
        else:
            result.append('')
    return result
        
df.style.apply(highlight_top3)
```

[image]